# horizontal uiscrollview

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to implement a horizontal uiscrollview. I want the user to the be able to swipe to the next view and I am not concerned about the user knowing what page they are on (there are only 2 views). I believe they call this page control.

So in my IB I have a default view which then I have added a UIScrollView into it and linked its referencing outlet (called scrollView). I have put all the UILabels and images that were previously in the default view into the scrollView.

I then created another empty view by dragging it into IB and linked it as well calling it newView. It is a separate object and not put into the default view.

Then in my view controller viewDidLoad I use the following code:

```
  [self->scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self->scrollView setDelegate:self];
self->scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self->scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[self->scrollView setIndicatorStyle:UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleDefault]; scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
scrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
[self->scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1300.0,0)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

It does not work. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: what issue you are facing i.e Are you getting only one view or what?

Comment: It does not works means what is happening ?

Comment: I tried it on one sample app & works fine for me.

Comment: @ernaidu It just will not swipe to the right...

Comment: @V-Xtreme it will not swipe horizontally

Comment: @AlexG: Change this `[self->scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1300.0,0)];` to `[self->scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1300.0,700)];`

Comment: If you have added scrollview via IB then you dont need to set these properties in viewDidLoad unless and untill you want to override them. Also when you have added scrollview via IB it is automatically added to main view, so you dont need to add it again in viewDidLoad method. [self.view addSubview:scrollView] is not required. Also please try what @AlexG suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove following line from your code:

```
[self->scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
```

Also you don't required :

```
[self->scrollView setIndicatorStyle:UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleDefault]; scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

And add

```
[self->scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1300.0,200.0)];
```

Also set xib to its default settings

Try this this should work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @V-Xtreme is right but missing one thing and is the paging which is mentioned in question by PO :)

So for paging enabled there are two ways:

1. From coding: Just put one line of code `[self->scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];`
2. Or In xib: Just Click on the `Paging Enabled` option ie. make sure that it is checked.

[image]